# Ajuda com MongoDB

Tags: sql, mongodb

Estou com um problema ao utilizar o `.find()` do mongoDB com RegExp. Tenho o seguinte comando:

```
db.collection.find({"city": /SAOPAULO/})
```

Quando faço:

```
db.collection.find({"city": /SAO/})
```

ele pesquisa na hora, mas quando passo uma palavra grande ele demora a carregar:

```
db.collection.find({"city": /SAOPAULO/})
```

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

> `SAOPAULO` fica lento se comparado com `SAO`.

Comment: A consulta funciona, mas fica mais lenta com `SAOPAULO` se comparada com  a `SAO`? Este comportamento é consistente?

Comment: @Dherik Isso mesmo. cada vez maior a string mais lento o mongo fica. eu defini um limite de 20 respostas por chamada com o .find(20) para ficar um pouco mais rápido.

Comment: Está utilizando índice para esta coluna?

Comment: @Dherik Sim. Estou usando índice nas colunas que utilizo. Será que tem alguma coisa relacionada a quantidade de dados da minha tabela?

Comment: Tem sim. Pelo que entendi lendo aqui, parece que ao procurar por um prefixo, a busca acaba sendo mais rápida. Veja este [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33219393/2387977). Parece ser um caso parecido com o seu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que é um comportamento esperado.

De acordo com a [documentação do MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) (grifo meu):

> For case sensitive regular expression queries, if an index exists for
>   the field, then MongoDB matches the regular expression against the
>   values in the index, which can be faster than a collection scan.
>   Further optimization can occur if the regular expression is a **“prefix
>   expression”, which means that all potential matches start with the
>   same string**. This allows MongoDB to construct a “range” from that
>   prefix and only match against those values from the index that fall
>   within that range.
>
> A regular expression is a “prefix expression” if it starts with a
>   caret (^) or a left anchor (\A), followed by a string of simple
>   symbols. For example, the regex /^abc.*/ will be optimized by matching
>   only against the values from the index that start with abc.

Ou seja, para `/SAOPAULO/`, o mongo vai buscar em quase todas as chaves do index para encontrar os registros que casam com esta busca, no qual provavelmente já será mais rápido que uma busca por toda a coleção de registros (o que já compensa a criação do índice).

Para `\SAO\`, o mongo irá escanear apenas o intervalo dos índices que iniciam com este valor. Assim, ele terminará mais rápida a consulta no índice, pois trata-se de um valor menor que `\SAOPAULO\` (no qual percorrerá mais partes do índice).

Assim, é esperado que a consulta pelo porção inicial da palavra desejada seja mais rápida do que pela palavra inteira.

Comment: Tentei usando `/^a/`, `/^a.*/`, `/^a.*$/`, `/a/`. A mais rápida foi `/a/` mas ainda assim está lento as outras estão levando na media de 3 segundos para responder. Usando `/sao/` a busca leva 0ms e quando coloco `/saopaulo/` o tempo vai para 1s

Comment: Desculpa, mas acho que não entendi bem sua pergunta. Estou achando estranho o tempo de resposta variar muito em relação ao tamanho da minha query

Comment: @usuario, editei, veja se minha explicação ficou mais clara.

Comment: Agora entendi. Vlw!

Comment: Andei lendo a documentação do mongo e achei o $text $serach. será que ele pode me ajudar?

Comment: @usuario, acredito que não. O que este método faz é simplificar a busca, tirando um pouco de código da parte do usuário e assumindo algumas coisas, funcionando mais como um utilitário. Não parece fazer diferença na performance. Contudo, você pode tentar e ver se sente alguma diferença :)

Comment: Usando o $text $search consegui a performance que queria. mas tive outro problema que ele não funciona com regex

Comment: Entendi. É verdade, pelo fato de não usar regex, poderia existir sim variação na performance com o `text` (esqueci do Regex).